# How can my Canon inkjet printer's black cartridge be drained after just ~100 pages?

Tags: printing, printer, inkjet-printer, ink, cartridge

I recently bought a super-expensive duo ink cartridge package for my Canon printer which I take out from the wardrobe every few years and realize that I have to buy new ink each time.

It was called "CANON 2970B010 PG-510 / CL-511" and cost, translated to USD, $33, not including shipping, and contained one "black" cartridge and one "color" cartridge, just as my printer (a "Canon PIXMA iP2700") expects. Official product. In the past, I've used third-party cartridges and they always report "low ink" immediately after being installed.

Other than a few test prints, the primary purpose was to print out one letter of 50 A4 pages (entirely consisting of black text, Times New Roman, 10pt), with "normal" quality. That is, 25 sheets which were printed on both sides with "manual duplex".

Yesterday, I printed out the same letter again, this time using "high" quality (since the "normal" quality setting made the text look quite "wrinkly" in places). The high quality mode takes much longer, but gives a result which one would expect: it looks "right".

In addition to this, I printed out a very small number (~10) of photos on A4 papers, using the high quality setting. Since a lot of those photos were color-based, you'd think (and I expected) it to drain the "color" cartridge, but it's barely been used at all according to the statistics reported by the printer!

The black cartridge, on the other hand, is entirely drained now, warning me repeatedly for the last few prints.

So basically, I printed only ~100 A4 pages of b/w text and that drained the entire thing?

Can this really be... real? I fully expected to be able to print "thousands" or at the very, very least a few hundred pages, and I thought the real problem would be the usual: that I use it so seldom that the ink has time to "go bad" so that it can't be used for that reason -- not that it would actually run out of ink that quickly!

Man, that sure was one expensive letter to print... And this makes me extremely skeptical to the entire concept of printing. I assume that laser printers have to change their "ink" ("toner") just as often, and/or have some other disadvantage. (If not, why would they still be selling inkjets?)

Comment: An inkjet cartridge is not going to give you "thousands" or a "few hundred" prints. The one you got is rated for a max of 220 sides. By printing pictures, it probably increased the usage amount compared to the "sides" they used for testing which was probably just text. I've never had an inkjet cartridge live up to its estimated print amount. If you want something that is going to print a lot, you'll want a color laser printer if you plan on printing pics. Black toner cartridges will last you 1000-2000 pages, sometimes a bit more. Color will probably get you ~1000 pages.

Answer (score 2):

Some basic things to keep in mind.

1. Cartridge rated life is for "standard" pages, i.e. 5% coverage, a normal text-only letter. [This is an example](http://www.thecartridgefamily.com.au/uploads/5%2010%2015%2040%20percent%20yield%20TCF.pdf).[image]
2. Ink is also used whenever the printer is powered up, as well as when you manually purge a blocked jet.
3. Black is used in most colours, to increase the available colour range. For the same reason, mono photos will also use colour. Most A4 colour photos will in fact use more black ink than a standard page.
4. Most inkjet cartridges have a low rated page count (hundreds, vs thousands for lasers)
5. Inkjets are far slower and more expensive to use than lasers - but they print photos better than lasers.
6. Commercial photo printing is better still and far cheaper - but not immediate.

Comment: ↑ This. Inkjets are a cheaper initial investment & they produce better photos. For absolutely every other reason, get a laser. 'Ink' lasts years & never dries out. Get photos from snappy snaps.